# Background does not load properly when scrolled with chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, background

The following problem only occurs in Google Chrome. Firefox, Opera, Safari and IE are doing fine.

I have a background on my body:

```
background: url('../../../views/blog/images/achtergrond.png') 50% 0 fixed repeat-x;
```

Then when I scroll the page and then reload only a part of the image is displayed:

[image]

The full image should look like this:

[image]

*Note: [See the actual website](http://ons.urker.land/blog/item/29/dit-is-een-nieuw-stukje)*

Comment: Here it does seems to work properly on Ubuntu 14.04 in Chrome 37. Which version of Chrome are you running? I'll think this doesn't has anything to do with your website.

Comment: Which version? It works fine for me in Google Chrome Version 37.0.2062.124 m

Comment: It only occurs when you scroll the page down and then reload. PS, I use windows and latest version of chrome.

Answer (score 0):

Background loading is working fine in my chrome as well..
The issue may be you stoped the browser loading while image is loading:

**Also do this thing:**

Make the size of background image more smaller that will help you to download background more easilty and fast.. 
Right now your background image size is : 1.73MB
That is so huge...
Do this and background will load more fast and will not cause issue in any browser...

Comment: Your'e right I saved it with Photoshop with the save for web but I did not configure the quality. I shall try to make it smaller!

Comment: The image is now smaller but I still have problems with it.

Comment: No its working fine everywhere, i have tested it.. so you dn't need to worry bro..